# What does it mean to write template <> between "struct struct_name" and "{" when define a struct

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Some days ago, I asked a question below:

I'm trying to write a hash table demo. By using chain to solve hash collision. I want to write some code like below(pseudo code) that to check if the class put in hash table implement operator<. If the class key_type implements operator<, I can use red-black tree to contain the data, otherwise I can only use linked list.

and I got some code as:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
template <typename K, typename V, typename = void>
struct MyContainerT {
  using bucket_type = std::list<std::pair<K, V>>;
};

template <typename K, typename V>
struct MyContainerT<K, V, decltype(void(K{} < K{}))>{ // what does this line means
  using bucket_type = std::map<K, V>;
};

template <typename K, typename V>
using MyContainer = typename MyContainerT<K, V>::bucket_type;

class C {
public:
    int id;
    bool operator==(C &other) const {
        return id == other.id;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyContainer<int, int> c1;
    MyContainer<C, int> c2;
    c1[1] = 1;
    c2.push_back(std::make_pair(C{}, 1));
    return 0; 
}
```

I got confused at `// what does this line means`

1.Why could the struct MyContainerT defined twice? And what does it mean to write template `<K, V, ...>` when defining a struct?

2.I know the `MyContainer<C, int> c2` could only match the first MyContainerT because C has no operator< to satisfied `decltype(void(K{} < K{}))`. But how does `MyContainer<int, int> c1` match the second?(I thought int with < satisfied both MyContainerT and compiler would output something like 'struct MyContainerT is ambiguous')

Comment: it's a template specialization, it uses SFINAE to make sure that the K and V types can be compared. according to template overload resolution rules, if a specialization applies, it's more specialized and therefore not ambiguous.